# Solve this quadratic function $h = -0.0625t^2 + 3t - 20$

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

I am struggling with this question and need a help!

In a science experiment, a student is studying the relationship between the temperature and the growth of a plant. She develops the following quadratic model: $h = -0.0625t^2 + 3t - 20$, where h is the height of the plant, in cm, and t is the growing temperature, in °C.

- Determine the temperatures that result in a plant height of zero.
- Use your result from part a) to find the temperature that will maximize the height of the plant.
- Use the equation to determine the height of the plant grown at a temperature of $5$ °C. Comment on the domain of the mathematical model.
- Use your results above to construct a graph for this relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Temperatures that result in zero height:**

In this case, let $h=0$ and solve the quadratic equation for $t$.

We have: $$0=-0.0625t^2+3t-20$$

Multiply both sides by $-16$ to get:$$0=t^2-48t+320$$

And then you could factor and solve:

$$0=t^2-48t+320$$
$$0=(t-40)(t-8)$$

Now, we know that $0=t-40$ or $0=t-8$, so $t = 8, 40$.

So, the plant will have zero height at $8$ and $40$ degrees.

**2. Temperature that maximizes plant height:**

All you need to do is find where the vertex of the equation $h=-0.0625t^2+3t-20$ is when you graph it.

The $t$-value of the vertex will be the **average** of the two solutions you found to part 1.

**3. Height at $5$ degrees C:**

Plug in $5$ for $t$ into the model and simplify.

$h=-0.0625(5)^2+3(5)-20$

(the rest is just numerical calculations)

**4. Graph:**

I can't really help you with this one, but you should find that the graph is an upside-down "U" shape.

Comment: for part A, can we use this formula to solve it? t = (-b ± √(b2 - 4ac)) / 2a
 
where:
a = -0.0625
b = 3
c = -20
 ?

Comment: @BISHRAAHMED yes you can. the formula works for all quadratics.

Comment: For the first three parts, could you please solve them in steps so I can properly understand them? I'm just not getting them quite well.

Comment: @BISHRAAHMED I edited my answer. does this help?

Comment: thank you for your help and patience. for part2// the vertex at (24,16) just complete it for me, it would be a great help!

Comment: @BISHRAAHMED Basically, what the vertex you found means that at 24 degrees, the plant will reach a maximum height of 16 cm.

Comment: finally got it. thank you so much.

Comment: just to double check, shouldn't t=40? you wrote t=-40. the second value of t is -8 which is correct. I'm getting t=40 and t=-8

Comment: @BISHRAAHMED  Yes, t=40, but I got t=+8 instead of t=-8. You might want to check the method you solved the quadratic with...